# Orchard v.1.10 I need to update custom user field after creation

Tags: orchardcms

I am using Orchard v.1.10.0.0
I need to update custom user field after he is created.

workflow decision activity is missing
How do i do that without it?

Comment: Update with what? Have you enabled the workflow modules?

Comment: Yes. i am creating a user in the workflow and i want to edit 2 custom fields of the user with fields from the form. i see in the guides that you do that with decision activity, but i cant find it in the workflow activities

Comment: The decision activity is available when you enable the module 'Orchard.Scripting.CSharp'

Comment: @devqon thanks you very much. it solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by enabling module - "C# Scripting - Provides C# compiler services."